# How to use Same Short Cut key in menu items and child windows buttons?

Tags: wpf

Have used same short cut key option in menu Items and child window buttons.

Short cut key event fired in menu item when cursor focus in child window.But Child window events not fired. But i want to fired the events in child window buttons when used the short cut keys in child window.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into using [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

From above MSDN Link:

> Commands have several purposes. The first purpose is to separate the
>   semantics and the object that invokes a command from the logic that
>   executes the command. This allows for multiple and disparate sources
>   to invoke the same command logic, ...